# Journal id drop-down fails to appear in AX2009

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

One person has this problem in production environment: when creating a new payment journal (AR/Journals/Payment/Payment journal) and tries to select a journal name, the drop-down only flashes momentarily but will not appear so that they could select a journal name.

They can however type the name manually and AX accepts this with no problem.

No problems with other journals or users have been reported.

I've instructed the user to clear their usage data and theis .auc file was also deleted, but the problem persists. And since this is in production, the debugger has not been installed - I have a nagging shadow of a memory that I've encountered something like this before and it was solved with the debugger, but alas, bad squishy memory error.

Thoughts, suggestions?

Comment: Could be a lot of things. How does the user access AX, local client, terminalserver? Check the client version. Did the user test it on other workstations? Does it happen only in one system (PROD) or on all systems (TEST, ...) for this user?

Comment: @FH-Inway : User reports that this happens to only to them; in both in test and production; and even on other workstations.

Comment: I think you are on your own on this one. One more suggestion: physically sit next to the user when this happens, [layer 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_8) issues are known to happen.

Comment: how about delete the .KTI file with the .AUC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alas, this is now moot, since the customer moved off AX. Nothing I could think up worked and as it was impossible to check for "layer 8" because of distance, this will be forever unanswered.